# Creating secondary column with data from existing column

Tags: r

I need help creating a secondary column using partial data from my first column in my data frame. I currently have this:

```
Column 1 
300
400
200
100
24
80
```

I wish to have this:

```
Column 1   Column 2
300        100
400        24
200        80
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What structure is that in? Is it a vector, a data frame, a matrix, a list, something else?

Comment: Something like `matrix(your_column_1, ncol = 2)` should work just fine if your data is a vector.

Comment: @Gregor Sorry, it's in a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df
 #   A
 # 1 1
 # 2 2 
 # 3 3
 # 4 4
 # 5 5
 # 6 6

 as.data.frame(matrix(df$A, byrow=FALSE, ncol = 2))
 #   V1 V2
 # 1  1  4
 # 2  2  5
 # 3  3  6
```

OR

```
 as.data.frame(matrix(df$A, byrow=FALSE, nrow = 3))
 #   V1 V2
 # 1  1  4
 # 2  2  5
 # 3  3  6
```

Filling ROW WISE

```
as.data.frame(matrix(df$A, byrow=TRUE, ncol = 2))
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  2
# 2  3  4
# 3  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
as.data.frame(matrix(dd$Column1, ncol = 2))
#    V1  V2
# 1 300 100
# 2 400  24
# 3 200  80
```

Assuming your data is something like this:

```
dd = read.table(text = "Column1 
300
400
200
100
24
80", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also `split` the data frame and then `cbind`.

```
do.call(cbind,split(dd,rep(1:2,each=3)))
  Column1 Column1
1     300     100
2     400      24
3     200      80
```

Comment: Thank you for your response : ) How can I change the name of the both  columns? Also, how can I change the ratio in which they are split (i.e. two rows in column 1 and four rows in column 2)?

Comment: to cange the name just use the `setName` function ie`setName(mydata,mynames)`. To change the ratio, you will have to change the splitting factor. But in that case, you will be unable to `cbind` them since the two will not have equal number of rows